# caffe2 obtain learning rate: Can't find blob: gpu_0/conv1_w_lr

Tags: python, fetch, workspace, caffe2

the code to obtain the learning rate in resnet50_train.py is as follows:

```
learning_rate = workspace.FetchBlob(prefix + '/conv1_w_lr')
```

and when I run the code, errors occured:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/caffe2/caffe2/caffe2/python/examples/resnet50_trainer.py", line
>   475, in 
>       main()   File "/home/caffe2/caffe2/caffe2/python/examples/resnet50_trainer.py", line
>   471, in main
>       Train(args)   File "/home/caffe2/caffe2/caffe2/python/examples/resnet50_trainer.py", line
>   400, in Train
>       explog   File "/home/caffe2/caffe2/caffe2/python/examples/resnet50_trainer.py", line
>   163, in RunEpoch
>       learning_rate = workspace.FetchBlob(prefix + '/conv1_w_lr')   File "/home/caffe2-master/caffe2/build/caffe2/python/workspace.py", line
>   323, in FetchBlob
>       return C.fetch_blob(StringifyBlobName(name)) RuntimeError: [enforce fail at pybind_state.cc:152] ws->HasBlob(name). Can't find
>   blob: gpu_0/conv1_w_lr

what caused the problem? Should I re-compile any dependencies or if there is any other function can be employed to obtain learning rate?

Answer (score 0):

Before you run `FetchBlob(prefix + '/conv1_w_lr')` you can check what blobs exist in the workspace: `for b in workspace.Blobs(): print(b)`.

Perhaps `conv1_w_lr` exists without the prefix. Perhaps, you first need to RunNet to have all the blobs in the workspace.

Comment: thanks a lot. .
I reviewed resnet50_trainer.py on github and found it different from the version I downloaded. the way of getting learning_rate has changed...
learning_rate = workspace.FetchBlob(
        data_parallel_model.GetLearningRateBlobNames(train_model)[0]
    )
latest caffe2 was recompiled and now it's ok.